# pin point using google Maps in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is it possible to allow users of my app to mark places on a map I display using Google Maps API? I need to then save that location coordinates in Variable.

I've been looking through the whole web about google maps API, I found some code

But I am not sure which part is for pin point, also i do not need any other code

Anyone have an link or code or tutorial ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to allow users of my app to mark places on a map I display using Google Maps API?

Add a custom `Overlay` to the `MapView`. In your `Overlay`, override `onTap()` to be notified of when the user taps on the screen. You are given a `GeoPoint` of the tap, from which you can get the latitude and longitude to record.

Comment: can you give me example or tutorial , i am beginner and not that much with java and android,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is done by CommonsWare [**here**](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/src/com/commonsware/android/maptouch/NooYawk.java)

Also you can have onTap as mentioned by CW , but I think this will be more convinient as in map user are touch and pinch ..this will help them to better decide..this what I used in my apps..so use the above code for your requirement.Also,
First download the whole project and see how it works.

Comment: I have no idea how can i add this code to my Activity,because i have already MapActivity and Overlayitem so, i add Touchy class implements overlay and try to put the example in it, but it gives me RUN TIME ERROR! what should i do?